# svelte on drop event not getting called

Tags: drag-and-drop, svelte

I know this has to be something blindingly obvious but I'm not getting it. I have two divs, one draggable and the other with an `on:drop` which doesn't seem to be getting called when I drop the draggable div onto it. What am I missing?

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/8846d8b9674d42ae86a410dbb737fb79?version=3.35.0

```
<script>

</script>

<div on:drop={ () => {console.log( "drop" )} } >drop on me</div>

<div class="drag" draggable={true}>drag me</div>

<style>
    div {
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 10px;
        background: #fee;
    }
    .drag {
        cursor:grab;
        background: #efe;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 8):

Looks like dragover event needs a preventdefault;

```
<div 
    on:drop={ () => {console.log( "drop" )} } 
    on:dragover={(ev) => { ev.preventDefault() }}
>drop on me</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

with `on:dragenter` I had to provide `ondragover="return false"`.